# can't get gemfile to allow for bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I'm a ruby/rails newbie.

Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'
gem 'wash_out', :git => 'git://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out.git'
gem 'haml'
gem "railties", "~> 4.0.0"

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end
```

On bundle update, I get this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      railties (= 4.0.0) ruby

    sass-rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      railties (4.0.1.rc1)
```

The sass-rails issue should be solved since I'm using ~> correct?  How can I have both rails and sass-rails installed at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put `sass-rails` before `rails` in your Gemfile, it resolves correctly.

Comment: Indeed it does, why does that work if I can only use one version of a gem at a time, as per jibender's answer below?

Comment: I'm not sure what he means by his answer. Your Gemfile looks OK to me, I think this is a resolution bug in Bundler.

Comment: What he said make sense to me though.  I only selected your answer because it was an easier fix (but I don't understand why it works).  I can only use one version of railties, correct?  And sass-rails requires 4.0.1 or greater whereas rails requires 4.0.0 exactly.  So why does this work?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed one difference between sass-rails 4.0.0 and sass-rails 4.0.1: version 4.0.0 depends on `'railties', '>= 4.0.0.beta', '< 5.0'` but 4.0.1 depends on `'railties', '>= 4.0.0', '< 5.0'`. Including 'beta' in the dependency allows pre-release versions, which is why it resolved to 4.0.1.rc1. When you upgrade to sass-rails 4.0.1, it no longer includes a pre-release version in its dependencies, so it will only allow released versions. So Jonathan Bender's answer is a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you can only use one version of a gem at a time. the `~>` will only allow for version changes on that gem.

You need to change the version of `sass-rails` you're requiring to `4.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

You should update the following line in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
```

to

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```

and then run `bundle update`.