# Is it necessary to update the line of gem in Gemfile when using bundle update gem-name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I want to update my `jquery_rails` gem, actual version is 3.0.4, the following command will update it

```
bundle update jquery_rails
```

so, what about my Gemfile, it is necessary to update version of jquery_rails too ? ("i work currently in local")

in my Gemfile i have version 2.2.1

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
```

**Update**

i change gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1' in my Gemfile to gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4', and i tried to execute `bundle update jquery-rails`but an error is occur :

```
 Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
In Gemfile:
rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
  railties (= 4.0.0) ruby

sass-rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
  railties (4.0.1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should update your gem file and specify required version of the gem, then run bundle update jquery_rails.

Error tells you, that you have gems which required different version of railties. Try to change versions of rails to 4.0.1, sass-rails to 4.0.1 and railties to 4.0.1 and update these gems via bundle.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, in this case yes it *is* necessary to update the version in `Gemfile`, but it is not always.

Running `bundle update <gem>` will cause Bundler to find the most recent version of the gem and its dependencies that satisfies all of the requirements of the `Gemfile`. Since you have specified a requirement of a specific version, Bundler will only allow that version. You can also specify a more flexible version in your `Gemfile`: `gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.2.0'` would allow it to use any 2.2.x version, or `'~> 2.2'` would allow any 2.x.

The issue with `sass-rails` is separate. You can solve it by updating to `sass-rails` 4.0.1. See [can't get gemfile to allow for bundle update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439302/cant-get-gemfile-to-allow-for-bundle-update/19448503#comment28945610_19448503)