# Why is older version of sass-rails require higher version of railties (Bundler)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, railtie

I have in my Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```

This works fine. If I run bundle update it says "Using sass-rails (4.0.1)". Now if I try to change it to use 4.0.0 (`gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'`) and run bundle update, it gives me error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      railties (= 4.0.0) ruby

    sass-rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      railties (4.0.1)
```

I don't understand why lower version sass-rails requires higher version railties? That seems strange to me, how can that be? In fact that's a lie!

In another project (Rails Tutorial sample_app) I have

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
```

and only railties (4.0.0), yet bundle update works fine. So it seems the error above is not the problem. Then I don't know what is?!

I found more info here - [can't get gemfile to allow for bundle update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439302/cant-get-gemfile-to-allow-for-bundle-update) (if I switch order of rails and sass-rails in gemfile then 4.0.0 works fine).
However it still doesn't make sense why my Gemfile works fine in one project and not the other with the same sass-rails and rails gems and the same railties.

Comment: it might just simply be a bug. sass-rails 4.0.0 depends on railties 4.0.0.beta and not just 4.0.0. so there might be a resolution issue here

Comment: Then it shouldn't have worked in sample_app project, yet it does. There I also have rails 4.0.0 and sass-rails 4.0.0 and bundle update doesn't give me any error.