# Railties compatibility issues when deploying to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I tried putting sass-rails before rails suggested in the post [Bundler gem compatibility issues when deploying to heroku.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437114/bundler-gem-compatibility-issues-when-deploying-to-heroku) but it didn't work.

Heroku Error Message

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
In Gemfile:
rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
railties (= 4.0.0) ruby

sass-rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
railties (4.0.1.rc1)

Failed to install gems via Bundler.
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end

gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Comment: It works now I forgot to commit :)

Answer (score 2):

Change the sass entry to :

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```

Then run bundle update, commit and redeploy